# Retrieving features from MSSQL to OpenLayers and displaying them?

Tags: openlayers-2, sql-server

Today I have a table in the DB with columns Feature Name and Feature Point.

When I want to load the points to OL I do the following :

1. First I call web service to get list of json objects:

   var request = OpenLayers.Request.POST( { url:
    "../service.asmx/GetCameraFeatures", async: false, data: "{}",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
    callback: this.callbackLoadCameras});
2. I parse points to features and add to the layer:

> ```
> var objArr = eval('(' + request.responseText + ')').d;
>         var jsonFormat = new OpenLayers.Format.JSON();
>         var features = jsonFormat.read(objArr);       
>         var format = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
>         var featuresArr = [];
>
>     for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
>         var f1 = format.read(features[i].point);
>       f1.id = features[i].name;
>         featuresArr.push(f1);
>     }
>
>     if (featuresArr.length > 0) {
>         cosmeticLayer.addFeatures(featuresArr);
>     }
> ```

Is there a better way to do this ? faster? more convenient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use ASP.NET Handler (.ashx) for object requests.
Web Services may look older technology than WCF services,but in technique they are similar.You can use them as well.

If I wish to present json in ASP.NET,I think of two ways:

One of which,If I wish to **change the content of my json** by adding properties to each feature etc.,then I simply create a class containing all values of my content and serialize JSON and serve within my handler as response.

Second one is,serve directly from your **database as json string with or without using services** (simple get request would be enough) by implementing stored procedures and functions,I use one in Oracle for SDO_Geometry that I hope there are similar one in MSSQL Spatial.

For performance:

- I suggest to use gzip in IIS,your json content shall be less size.
- There are some techniques [here](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/) which you should avoid in serialization
- And there is a comparison between frameworks [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/27/json-net-3-5-beta-1-big-performance-improvements-compact-framework-support-and-more.aspx)

Best Regards
Myra

Comment: Thanks Myra.
How do you parse the items in OpenLayers ? 
Do you use KML layer ? Vector layer and adding the features ? or using directly HTTP layer ?

Comment: Depends on the project actually,but basically for vectors I always use GeoJSON layers.Others can be used as well.Please look at OpenLayers.Format specification.If you can serve as supported format,you do not need to parse objects at all.Putting a format option in OpenLayers.Layer would be sufficient.

Comment: Care to link an example for good start ? :)

Comment: There are lots of examples on the internet,start with OpenLayers examples http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/